# Trazer a frente um programa já aberto - C#

Tags: c#

Tenho um programa que, ao tentar executar, e já estiver aberto, ele manda uma mensagem avisando que o mesmo já está em execução, mas, eu queria saber uma maneira de trazer o programa pra frente quando eu tentar abrir ele.

Código:

```
    class InicializaPrograma
    {
        static System.Threading.Mutex _mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, name: "7d89086c-8e9f-43c8-8acd-d8cf877f48ca");

        [System.STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            if (_mutex.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan.Zero, true))
                try
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Programa());
                }
                finally { _mutex.ReleaseMutex(); }
            else System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Já existe um Gerador de Deck aberto.", "Gerador de Deck", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Por exemplo, se o programa estiver aberto, é verificado o GUID, e traz o programa correspondente pra frente...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando que:

1. Instância "A" da aplicação rodando.
2. Abrir uma nova instância "B".
3. A instância "B" verifica se já há outra instância em execução.
4. Resultado positivo, "A" está em execução.
5. Encerra a instância "B".

Você quer que, antes de encerrar a instância "B", a instância "A" seja colocada em primeiro plano ou restaurar a janela caso esteja minimizada.

Como a instância "B", não tem controle sobre a instância "A", e "A" não conhece a tentativa de abrir "B", você precisa utilizar a API do Windows para que a instância "B" possa trazer A para frente.

> Exemplo 1:

```
static class Program
{

     [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
     public static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab);

    [System.STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (_mutex.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        { 
            try
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Programa());
            }
            finally { _mutex.ReleaseMutex(); }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Já existe um Gerador de Deck aberto.", "Gerador de Deck", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            System.Diagnostics.Process[] ps = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(p.ProcessName);
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process pp in ps)
            {
                if (pp.Id != p.Id)
                {
                    Program.SwitchToThisWindow(pp.MainWindowHandle, true);
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

> Exemplo 2:

```
static class Program
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [System.STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (_mutex.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        { 
            try
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Programa());
            }
            finally { _mutex.ReleaseMutex(); }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Já existe um Gerador de Deck aberto.", "Gerador de Deck", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            System.Diagnostics.Process[] ps = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(p.ProcessName);
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process pp in ps)
            {
                if (pp.Id != p.Id)
                {
                    Program.SetForegroundWindow(pp.MainWindowHandle);
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Desculpe se ficou um pouco confuso com esses "A" / "B", rsrs
o primeiro exemplo, é como já utilizei.

O segundo, encontrei aqui: http://www.webskaper.no/wst/creatingasingleinstanceapplicationinc-aspx/

Há um detalhe que você testa se há outra instância pelo GUID, enquanto para conseguir o `MainWindowHandle` precisamos do nome do processo. A função não irá funcionar caso a segunda instância seja uma cópia do executável com outro nome.

> Detalhes sobre as funções `SetForegroundWindow` e `SwitchToThisWindow`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12203109/4713574

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Muito bom! A primeira dica funcionou perfeitamente :)
Obs: Precisei substituir "Program.SwitchToThisWindow(pp.MainWindowHandle, true);"
para "SwitchToThisWindow(pp.MainWindowHandle, true);"

Muito obrigado! <3

Comment: certo, no exemplo eu utilizo uma `static class Program`, por isso a diferença. Mas tudo certo, obrigado =]

Comment: Ahh sim, não tinha visto huehueh
Se quiser ver, estou fazendo um programa em C#, como vc tbm gosta de C# :v

https://github.com/lucasnaja/deckgenerator